# How to auto-fit my map inside RVIZ2 in real-time?

Tags: ros2, rviz

I’m using ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu 22
I am currently using a SLAM program called Google Cartographer.
This program updates and displays the SLAM Map in real time through a program called RVIZ2.
This SLAM Map generates and updates the indoor map in real time, using the current location of the robot, the direction it is facing, and each sensor value information when an autonomous robot equipped with a ToF sensor and an IMU sensor moves indoors.
The problem is that when the overall size of the map changes as the map is updated, the entire map cannot be displayed in the view area of RVIZ2.

So may I ask how to do below ?

When the map is updated, the total size of the map is automatically detected and RVIZ2 finds a way to display the entire map by centering it in the view area.
In other words, RVIZ2 automatically calculates the center of the map and the maximum size of the map and resizes it to fit the view area.

Hope you have a happy new year !

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
RViz is listening to a ROS topic and updates the view upon receiving a new ROS message. Can you please confirm if the new message was actually published in the first place? RViz should be able to update the view automatically.

Comment: Hello, ravi. I can accept your suggestion. But what do I need to do to inform you of new message?